# Coldfusion Regex get strings between tags

Tags: regex, coldfusion, coldfusion-8

We currently have some application variables being defined on our apps and also have a special set of tags that are processed within our templates. However I'm finding it to be a bit difficult to split the tags, so I can convert them to application variables when parsed by the template.

```
<cfset mystring = "[pss]'fetchMessages','VWO-Tracking-Code'[end_pss]">
<cfset the_match = REMatch("\[pss\]\s*(((?!\[pss\]|\[end_pss\]).)+)\s*\[end_pss\]",mystring) />
<cfdump var="#the_match#" />
```

Our goal is to split the strings between the "[pss] and [end_pss]"

The regex above simply takes the string and applies it to a CF array, which is all good. However I strictly want the code between it as I'll be able to convert it to

```
<cfset application.snippets['VWO-Tracking-Code']>
```

Right now it returns everything as one string and I also require the first portion to determine what type of functionality is required.

Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated.

We are currently using CF 8 and the structure of the code is exactly the same all the time. The only thing is it can be contained within other strings of code as well...

Comment: _"The only thing is it can be contained within other strings of code as well..."_ - you mean it can be nested? Regex becomes a bad choice when dealing with nested constructs...

Comment: Regarding _"however i strickly want the code between it"_ and _"i also require the first portion"_ - you need to be clearer on _specifically_ what you need. Is the "first portion" the `pss` or the `fetchMessages`. If the latter, is `pss` a static string? What is the context of this - i.e. can `[` occur outside of the tags? Is mystring the entire string or part of a substring?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only doing this for one set of tags you can use the `replaceList` function rather than regEx

```
<cfset mystring = "[pss]'fetchMessages','VWO-Tracking-Code'[end_pss]">
<cfset mystring = replaceList(mystring,"[pss],[end_pss],'",'')>
<cfset firstitem = listfirst(mystring)>
<cfset seconditem = listlast(mystring)>
<cfdump var="#firstitem#">
<cfdump var="#seconditem#">
```

This outputs `fetchMessages` and `VWO-Tracking-Code`. If you want/need the single quotes on your strings then you can remove the `,'` from the 2nd parameter of the `replaceList` function.

Comment: Can get these two values just by treating it as a quote-delimited list - i.e. `ListGetAt(mystring,2,"'")` and `ListGetAt(mystring,4,"'")` (or if quotes are important, use `,[]` as delimiters and get positions 2 and 3).